# how to restrict installation of an android app from google play store to a single phone

Tags: android, google-play

I am in a position to develop an android app for a client. But that app has to be installed only in the client's mobile phone. Others should not be able to install that app from Google Play store. Is this possible?

Comment: You can add programmatic checks on your 1st Activity. Get your client's deviceID store it in String.XML, then in your code (1st activity launched), get the Device ID, compare it to the String.XML Device ID, if they match, run the app. Or else if they do not match, Block the app, throw an error, Show message or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload it as alpha or beta and only add him to test users.

Although I don't see why you would upload it to the playstore at all you can also just send him the apk file.

Comment: Ya i know, But i just like to know that is there any way to do that in google play store.

Comment: With alpha or beta it is possible I personally have only tried it using google communities. So you make a community with your google account then add the people you would like to test/use the app to the community and set the test users to that community in the google play console. From there on you only need to share the given link.

Answer (score 0):

@Selva, I wonder what is the need to upload app on Google Play in your case.

Comment: Then installing that app in client's mobile using apk file is enough. Is this the one are trying to say?